# Organizing requires and moving them to document Top

Tags: node.js, abstract-syntax-tree, jscodeshift

I am organizing code in a app. The require statements are un-organized so I made this codemod to sort them and to add them on top of the page.

[The codemod works](https://astexplorer.net/#/HPwPYV4rcI), almost perfect. I have some doubts:

- is this a ok approach, or is there a more correct way to use the API?
- how can I keep the empty line between the `sourceStart` (all the requires) and the rest of the source code?
- can a similar approach be used in ES6 imports? (ie to sort them with jscodeshift)

My Initial code:

```js
var path = require('path');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var async = require('async');

let restOfCode = 'foo';
```

My codemod:

```js
let requires = j(file.source).find(j.CallExpression, {
    "callee": {
        "name": "require"
    }
}).closest(j.VariableDeclarator);

let sortedNames = requires.__paths.map(node => node.node.id.name).sort(sort); // ["async", "express", "path", "stylus"]
let sortedRequires = [];
requires.forEach(r => {
    let index = sortedNames.indexOf(r.node.id.name);
    sortedRequires[index] = j(r).closest(j.VariableDeclaration).__paths[0]; // <- feels like a hack
});

let sourceStart = j(sortedRequires).toSource();
let sourceRest = j(file.source).find(j.CallExpression, {
    "callee": {
        "name": "require"
    }
}).closest(j.VariableDeclaration)
.replaceWith((vD, i) => {
    // return nothing, it will be replaced on top of document
})
.toSource();

return sourceStart.concat(sourceRest).join('\n'); // is there a better way than [].concat(string).join(newLine) ?
```

And the result I got:

```js
var async = require('async');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var stylus = require('stylus');
var router = express.Router(); // <- I would expect a empty line before this one

let restOfCode = 'foo';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is this a ok approach, or is there a more correct way to use the API?

You shouldn't be accessing `__paths` directly. If you need to access all NodePaths, you can use the `.paths()` method. If you want to access the AST nodes, use `.nodes()`.

E.g. the mapping would just be

```
let sortedNames = requires.nodes()(node => node.id.name).sort(sort);
```

> how can I keep the empty line between the `sourceStart` (all the requires) and the rest of the source code?

There isn't really a good way to do this. See [this related recast issue](https://github.com/benjamn/recast/issues/147). Hopefully this will become easier one day with CSTs.

> can a similar approach be used in ES6 imports? (ie to sort them with jscodeshift)

Certainly.

---

FWIW, here is my version (based on your first version):

```
export default function transformer(file, api) {
    const j = api.jscodeshift;
    const sort = (a, b) => a.declarations[0].id.name.localeCompare(
        b.declarations[0].id.name
    );

    const root = j(file.source);
    const requires = root
      .find(j.CallExpression, {"callee": {"name": "require"}})
      .closest(j.VariableDeclaration);
    const sortedRequires = requires.nodes().sort(sort);

    requires.remove();

    return root
      .find(j.Statement)
      .at(0)
      .insertBefore(sortedRequires)
      .toSource();
    };
}
```

https://astexplorer.net/#/i8v3GBENZ7